# freeipa 4.1.0 on fedora20 not working

Tags: freeipa, fedora-20

Has anyone successfully setup freeipa 4.0.3 on Fedora20 as a server and another fedora20 with freeipa 4.1.0 for the client side? because I can't figure out why im always having the error " user does not exist" when using " su - (user)@ipaserver.com "

I've configured nsswitch.conf as well

sudoers : files sss ldap

although I haven't changed sssd.conf

what should I add in the configurations??

plus when I'm using freeipa 4.1.0 as a server and setting up the DNS forwarders , it always shows the error that the dns does not respond, ( in my case I'm using the ip address of the ipa server for the dns forwarder )

please help! I've been at these errors for 3 weeks now

Comment: You shouldn't need to specify the domain with the `su` command.

Comment: but in the other guides I see in the internet they specify it plus it still says user does not exist.

Comment: I never use the domain, and it works. Are you correctly joined to the domain? Can you get a ticket with `kinit`?